# How to delete a graph schema using Gremlin

Tags: graph, titan, gremlin, tinkerpop, tinkerpop3

This question refers to Gremlin 3.0.2.

I want to delete the schema of a graph in order to clear out all metadata in the backend storage

Using Java to talk to Titan one could write

```
graph.close();
TitanCleanup.clear(graph);
```

Is there something similarly simple available in Gremlin? To make it more clearly, it's not about deleting all vertices and edges of the graph. This has already been done at this point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of v3.2.x, TinkerPop only provides an API for graph elements (`Structure`) and traversals (`Process`). It doesn't provide an abstraction over graph schema (properties and indexes): this is left to the responsibility of the implementer and the end user must use these third-party APIs.

You can dig the [official TinkerPop mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/gremlin-users) for relevant discussions on the topic.